# How to add wildcarded mapper paths in MyBatis configuration?

Tags: java, configuration, mybatis

In MyBatis [documentation](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#mappers) I see only example of adding mappers by exact name.

```
<mappers>
  <mapper resource="org/mybatis/builder/AuthorMapper.xml"/>
  <mapper resource="org/mybatis/builder/BlogMapper.xml"/>
  <mapper resource="org/mybatis/builder/PostMapper.xml"/>
</mappers>
```

Specifying each mapper name looks like a redundant verbosity, and I am wondering if there is a way to do the same with wildcards like this:

```
<mappers>
  <mapper resource="org/mybatis/builder/*Mapper.xml"/> 
</mappers>
```

In `mybatis-spring-boot-starter` they have a property `mybatis.mapper-locations` that could be used as follows:

```
mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath:org/mybatis/builder/*Mapper.xml
```

The only disadvantage is that it involves tons code and Spring autoconfiguring magic under the hood.

**Is it possible to add wildcarded mappers path into config xml using MyBatis itself (without Spring dependencies)?**

*or is there a reason why this useful feature is not available?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that same documentation page - you can register a package and all interfaces in the package will be registered. This is far less verbose than registering mappers individually:

```xml
<!-- Register all interfaces in a package as mappers -->
<mappers>
  <package name="org.mybatis.builder"/>
</mappers>
```

Comment: Actually, I wanted to keep SQL queries in XML files for readability. But, I suppose, at some step (size of a project) referencing a package with annotated mappers will be the trade off removing long enumeration of all mappers in XML.

Comment: Annotated mappers are not required - it will work for XML based mappers. If the XML file is named the same as the corresponding Java interface interface and in the same package, MyBatis will find it.